# Fastest way of updating a spider web of data

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, query, recursive

I have a large table with over 60 million rows, which has relational data inside of it.  I need to update each of these rows to the newest date, of the newest member, including members that that member is a part of.  The problem I'm having is my queries are too slow, especially when I need to run them in a loop until everything is updated.

Example:

| id | type | refid | reftype | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Team | 1 | Person | 2021-04-03 |
| 1 | Team | 2 | Person | 2021-03-31 |
| 2 | Team | 2 | Person | 2021-04-01 |
| 2 | Team | 3 | Person | 2021-04-02 |
| 1 | Group | 1 | Team | 2021-04-03 |
| 2 | Group | 2 | Team | 2021-04-05 |
| 3 | Team | 4 | Person | 2021-03-31 |

In the above data, all rows except the last one would be updated to "2021-04-05", because Group 2 contains Team 2, and Team 2 contains Person 2, which is also a member of Team 1, which is a member of Group 1.  Same thing would have happened if Person 2 was the newest date. So you can see the confusion and the massive growth of possible connections. In the end I just need to expire anything over a week.

Currently I run a loop of the two queries below until both return 0, but this can take a ton of passes and take over 10+ minutes each time for the second query.  I have combined indexes, but It seems the need to process the sheer 16GB data size takes a while.  Am I missing something, or is there a better way? Appreciate any help!

```
update table_name
            left outer JOIN
            table_name AS t2 ON t2.refid = table_name.refid AND t2.reftype = table_name.reftype AND t2.TIMESTAMP >= DATE('2021-04-01')
            set table_name.timestamp = t2.timestamp
            WHERE
            t2.timestamp IS NOT NULL
            AND date(t2.timestamp) > date(table_name.timestamp)
            AND table_name.TIMESTAMP < DATE('2021-04-01');
```

followed by

```
update table_name
            left outer JOIN
            table_name AS t2 ON t2.id = table_name.id AND t2.type = table_name.type AND t2.TIMESTAMP >= DATE('2021-04-01')
            set table_name.timestamp = t2.timestamp
            WHERE
            t2.timestamp IS NOT NULL
            AND date(t2.timestamp) > date(table_name.timestamp)
            AND table_name.TIMESTAMP < DATE('2021-04-01');
```

Using 10.5.9-MariaDB, but can switch/upgrade to whatever DB is best for the job.  Analyze statement shows indexes are being used.  timestamp field is datetime, but example shows date only for simplicity.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: What version of MySQL?  You may need CTEs of version 8.0.

Comment: What datatype is `timestamp`?  Looks like it is already `DATE`, in which case, `DATE()` is not needed.

Comment: I'm running 10.4.10-MariaDB, but I am not tied down to any specific database or version for this problem.  The timestamp is a datetime, so I added DATE in order to speed things up and avoid running updates on rows with the same date but different times.  I need Time in the data, but I'm expiring on Date.

Comment: *Updated to 10.5.9-MariaDB for some new features introduced in 10.5.2.

Comment: Include `show create table xx` information, at least for the columns and indexes in your question, and `explain update ...` information. `DATE('2021-04-01')` isn't sane `'2021-04-01'` is a date. Don't do a `left join` if you have `t2.timestamp IS NOT NULL`. Drop the criteria and use a (non-left) `join`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have worded my question better.  The examples are simplified in order to give a quick overview of the main problem.  I'm hoping someone can help me with an alternate way of looking at the problem, versus tweaking what I have.  Date function and Left Join have no significant effect.  So for example, could this be done better with a recursive cte query?  I have a cte query that can check a single record, but I'm unsure how to apply it to an entire table this size without a loop or if it would actually cover all of the paths on a single run.